# Show example row when a DELETE fails due to a foreign key constraint

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I am trying to delete some old historic data from a MySQL database with multiple tables.
There is a "volumes" table, and a "metadata" table. Of course, you can't have metadata for a volume that does not exist, so there is a foreign key constraint.

This is a query I'm trying to do:

```
DELETE FROM volumes 
       WHERE deleted > 0 AND 
             deleted_at IS NOT NULL AND 
             deleted_at < '2020-01-01T00:00:00' AND 
             status = 'deleted' AND 
             attach_status = 'detached' 
       LIMIT 5000
```

This results in the following error (reformatted for readability):

```
Integrity error: 'DELETE FROM volumes WHERE deleted > 0 AND deleted_at IS NOT NULL AND deleted_at < '2020-01-01T00:00:00' AND status = 'deleted' AND attach_status = 'detached' LIMIT 5000' 
(1451, 'Cannot delete or update a parent row: 
        a foreign key constraint fails 
        (`volume_glance_metadata`, 
         CONSTRAINT `volume_glance_metadata_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`volume_id`) REFERENCES 
                                                                `volumes` (`id`))')
```

All answers I find if I try to search for this are answers to different questions, like "how can I delete this anyway" or "how can I remove the constraint"? That's not what I'm interested in though.

What I would like to know is: How can I find an example of a row from the `volumes` table that the `DELETE` query tried to delete, but cannot be deleted, because there is still a row in the `volume_glance_metadata` table that has the corresponding `id` (`volume_glance_metadata.volume_id = volumes.id`)? Or in other words: give me an example that makes the deletion fail.

I presume that there is at least one row that cannot be deleted; or maybe no row exists that can be deleted. It seems a bit disappointing that MySQL doesn't do its best to find *other* rows to delete, if there are some that would fail.

Comment: Don't you already have (at least) one: the one that produced this error?

Comment: Sure, there is a row that causes the error. But the message doesn't tell me *which* row it is! That is what frustrates me at the moment...

Comment: If I knew anything really about mysql I would be able to do that... but since I don't, I tried to resort to googling (and failed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do a SELECT with equivalent conditions on rows in `volumes`, and JOIN those rows to the dependent table `metadata`.

```
SELECT m.*
FROM volumes AS v
INNER JOIN metadata AS m ON m.volume_id = v.id
WHERE v.deleted > 0 
 AND v.deleted_at IS NOT NULL 
 AND v.deleted_at < '2020-01-01T00:00:00' 
 AND v.status = 'deleted' 
 AND v.attach_status = 'detached'
```

The join is an inner join, not an outer join, so it naturally returns only matching rows.

If this join query returns no rows in its result, then `metadata` contains no rows that would block your delete.

Comment: Thanks! When this query results in a non-empty set, is there any way one could know which of those rows was unluckily chosen by the DELETE query?

Comment: Does it matter? Any of them would block the delete.

Comment: Well, this database had some weirdness in it, like volumes which were not deleted at the same time as their metadata. Probably as a result of evolving software that uses the database. While cleaning up the old data, I was wondering if something like that was the case. It turns out it wasn't, but I didn't know how to check.

Comment: If the foreign key constraint is active and `FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1` then you cannot delete rows in `volumes` before deleting rows in `metadata` that reference them. But if you somehow disabled the foreign key checks, you might have some "orphaned" rows in `metadata`. Use an outer join to find them.

Comment: Fortunately that wasn't the case. The incremental deletion progress has now deleted sufficient rows from the `metadata` table that it could delete some rows from the `volumes` table.